# Need to save log in DB of every login attempt but getting syntax error

Tags: c#, mysql, database, visual-studio, ms-access

I'm trying to save log. I have a User table and a Userlog table. The username is my foreign key in Userlog table.One to many relation (one user can have many userlogs). I'm trying to save it but I'm getting syntax error. Also if you can tell me if the code is good or can it be more efficient.

```
public bool log(string user)
{
    OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(cs);
    conn.Open();

    string date = DateTime.Now.ToString();
    string query = "insert into UserLog(Username, TimeStamp) Values('"+user+"','"+date+"')";

    OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(query, conn);
    //cmd.Parameters.Add("@1", OleDbType.Char, 20).Value = user;
    //cmd.Parameters.Add("@2", OleDbType.Char, 20).Value = DateTime.Now;

    try
    {
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        throw;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: Your insert statement never closes the last set of parenthesis.

Comment: And **please** use parameters instead of building your sql string ad hoc!

Comment: It gives me error "INSERT INTO syntax error"

Comment: even with the last set of parenthesis it still gives me error.
I gave direct values just to test if the code works or not

Comment: You can also check you queries [online](http://www.piliapp.com/mysql-syntax-check/)

Answer (score 0):

There is an error near the end of your `insert` statement. Replace it by:

```
string query = "insert into UserLog(Username, TimeStamp) Values ('"+user+"','"+date+"');";
```

Comment: There is additional "." near `data` variable